# Rails 4 - Passing parameter from view to controller using form_tag

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I've got something seemingly simple that I need some help with, currently working in Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.0

I'm working on a payroll index page, where the user can select a week from a select_tag on the page. I have a @current_week variable in my payroll controller that I want to pass a parameter to, but I'm having some trouble doing so using a form_tag. Here's what I've got so far:

index.html.haml

```
%h1 Payroll Index
%h6= "Current Week: #{@current_week}"
.week_selector
=form_tag payroll_path, action: :update_week do
    =select_tag :current_week, options_from_collection_for_select(@weeks, 'id', 'start_date')
    =submit_tag
```

payroll_controller.rb

```
class PayrollController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @weeks = Week.all
    @current_week = params[:current_week] || Week.this_week.display_date
  end

  def update_week
    @current_week = params[:current_week] 
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :payroll, only: [:index, :update] do
    post '/:update_week' => 'payroll#index', as: :payroll
  end
...
```

Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to submit the form, and just update the @current_week variable in the controller, still staying on the index page. Surely there's a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

I've tried a few different combos in the routes andform, but haven't made much progress. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

As per infused's suggestion, I changed the form to the following:

```
  =form_tag payrolls_path, method: :get do
    =select_tag :current_week, options_from_collection_for_select(@weeks, 'id', 'start_date')
    =submit_tag
```

And received the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `payrolls_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101e045a0>:0x0000010c3af450>
```

As Requested, here is the relevant output of `rake routes`:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
   payroll_payroll POST   /payroll/:payroll_id/:update_week(.:format) payroll#index
     payroll_index GET    /payroll(.:format)                          payroll#index
           payroll PATCH  /payroll/:id(.:format)                      payroll#update
                   PUT    /payroll/:id(.:format)                      payroll#update
         employees GET    /employees(.:format)                        employees#index
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the `current_week` param to your index path set the method to GET:

```
= form_tag payroll_index_path, method: :get do
```

By default form_tag will use POST, which won't route to the index.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... I had tried that route, but I get the error: `No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"payroll"} missing required keys: [:id]`  I've tried passing things into the payroll_path, but that seems silly given that it's an index view?

Comment: Try `payrolls_path` in your form. If that doesn't work update your question with the output of `rake routes` for the payroll routes.

Comment: According to your routes output, you should be using `payroll_index_path`

Comment: I tried that as well, but with the same `missing required keys: [:id]` error. As a result, I've been messing around with passing different parameters into it, but with no luck. Any thoughts?